# Writing $n$ as $a*b$

Tags: algorithms

This was asked in a facebook interview .

> Given a number, find the number of ways you can split it into two
>   numbers such that each of them is greater than $1$ and both the
>   numbers don't have a common divisor and their product is equal to the
>   given number

can somebody give a code with an explanation ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can decompose $n$ in a product of prime numbers : $n = p_1^{n_1}...p_r^{n_r}$. Then, you only have to choose a subset $I \subset \{1, 2, ..., r \}$, $I \neq \emptyset$, $I \neq \{1, 2, ..., r \}$. You will have $a = \prod_{j \in I} p_j^{n_j}$, and $b = n/a$.

So the number of ways you are looking for is the number of such $I$ subsets, e.g. $2^r - 2$.

**Pseudo-code** :

```
if (n < 2) return 0;
r = 0; // Number of prime factors of n
n' = n;
for i = 2 to n do {
    if (n' mod i == 0)
        r++;
    while (n' mod i == 0)
        n' = n'/i;
    if (n' == 1) // All prime factors have been treated.
        break;
}
return 2^r - 2;
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate why it works ? I understand 2^r but why -2? like suppose you have for example 2,3,5 then 2^3 =8 ? Please explain with an example ? Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: Because $I \neq \emptyset$ and $I \neq \{1, 2, ..., r \}$.

Comment: @user2190178: If $n = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$ then the options are $a = 2, 3, 5, (2 \cdot 3), (2 \cdot 5), (3 \cdot 5)$ for a total of $6 = 2^3 - 2$ options, but not $a = 1$ or $a = (2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5)$ (because that would correspond to $I = \emptyset$ and $I = \{1, \ldots, r\}$ respectively).

Comment: @ TMM Thanks a ton !! :) That was really helpful :)

Comment: I've added a pseudo-code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the pseudo code:

```
for (prime p)
   { if (n==0 (mod p))
       k=max{j: n==0 (mod p^j)}
       we can then write out n=p^j(n/p^j)
   }
```

such that there are $|P(p \in prime: n=0 (mod p))|$ different possibilities.

So if $ n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{r_i}  $, then we can write n out like this in $ (2^k-2)/2=2^{k-1}-1 $ different ways, because we are not interested in the empty set or all of the set of indices (because that would be the entire number itself, and also choosing a set's compliment is the same as choosing the set itself (that's why we divide by 2).

Comment: Thank you !! But could you explain this part ?  
Because I≠∅ and I≠{1,2,...,r}. ?

Comment: This is a real **pseudo**-code...